# How do we access SEP2Agent code in Volttron

Tags: volttron

The documentation shows availability of SEP 2.0 Agent and Driver, but this agent/driver is unavailable in the GitHub code. Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently the SEP2 stuff is only available in the develop branch. It will move to master when VOLTTRON 5.0 is released.